# Lemmatization with Python and nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I need to lemmatize some words with Python

I have installed NLTK, but I get the following errors

```
Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
```

I have installed nltk and previously imported the library 
I would like to know why I have this error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had solved my problem by running

```
nltk.download('punkt')
```